# Difference between smallint and short?

Tags: sql, pyspark, short

Whats the difference between smallint and short in spark sql?

Comment: [I don't see a `smallint` type.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html)  I do see exactly one reference to the term "smallint" [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html), and that reference implies to me that it's not a separate type but just perhaps a Python-friendly name for the `short` type?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its just alias named  used in Spark SQL for ShortType.
Refer Table given in [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html#tab_SQL_0).

[image]